# Who sells these?

Tags: riddle, word

Can one buy Prestige?
Are Advantages sold?
For a yearly fee
Can one get Gold?

Which company offers all of these?

> Answer is the name of a company that offers the above.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> VISA [advantage](https://cafcu.org/?Cabinet=Main&Drawer=Loans+and+Visa+Cards&Folder=Visa+Credit+Cards&SubFolder=Visa+Advantage) [prestige](https://www.desjardins.com/ca/personal/loans-credit/credit-cards/visa-prestige-platinum/), and [gold](http://www.visa.ca/en/personal/cardsandproducts/visagold.jsp) cards all exist and presumably have an annual fee.

Comment: I suspect this is correct, although they aren't sold.

Comment: @HerbWolfe though the annual fee is a payment of money in exchange for something so would fit some definitions of a sale.

Comment: I didn't even know that they offer them. I had someone else in mind. But you are nevertheless correct.

Comment: @LN6595 another credit card provider or something different? If different unaccept my answer and see if someone else gets it.

Comment: @LN6595 or maybe add your own intended answer. And get some rep. free if people likes it... :p

Comment: Nah, just had Citi in mind. Yours is as correct as mine.

Comment: Please don't put links to corporate advertising on SE. Use Wikipedia or some other neutral site.

Comment: @PaulEvans the links are relevant as they provide examples that each of these cards exist in visa format. The answer to the question is ultimately about marketing names for commercial products. They are just the top Google result for each card type "in the wild". I've got no intention of wasting time trying to find a "neutral" site presenting this information. You can feel free to do so if the links offend you in some way.